# UITableView second & third label doesn't show values in the cell

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, uitableview

In my Tableview, the second and third label (with tags), doesn't show anything, it's blank. The second label should show "Test2" and the third label "Test3".

The label tags are already configured (1, 2 & 3). I've tried everything and still can't get this working .. :(

Here's my code :

```
import UIKit
import FirebaseDatabase
import FirebaseAuth

struct exerciseStruct {
    let exerciseName : String!
    let mainMuscle : String!
    let rate : String!
}

class ExercisesViewController: UITableViewController {

    var exercises = [exerciseStruct]()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.exercises.insert(exerciseStruct(exerciseName: "Test1", mainMuscle: "Test2", rate: "Test3"), atIndex: 0)

    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return exercises.count
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        var cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell")

        let label1 = cell!.viewWithTag(1) as! UILabel
        label1.text = exercises[indexPath.row].exerciseName

        let label2 = cell!.viewWithTag(2) as! UILabel
        label2.text = exercises[indexPath.row].mainMuscle

        let label3 = cell!.viewWithTag(3) as! UILabel
        label3.text = exercises[indexPath.row].rate

        return cell!
    }
}
```

**My tablecell :**

[image: My TableCell]

**Result :**
[image: Result]

What am I doing wrong here??

Thank you in advance!

Comment: why do you need tags ? You can just declare the three labels in the uitableviewcell subclass and access them directly.

Comment: I followed a tutorial I found on youtube, but with tags it should also work or not ??? @TejaNandamuri

Comment: Your code is correct. I think problem is related to the cell height. You should check your prototype cell size with the given size in storyboard(table view -> Row height).

Comment: just increase your cell height they should appear !!

Comment: yes, cell height could also be issue. BUt in future you cannot manage the views just by using tags. Tags are not meant for that purpose.

Comment: Thank you all for the tips!

Comment: *I followed a tutorial...* How old is that tutorial? Using standard `UITableViewCell` with tags is outdated. Look for a more up-to-date tutorial.

Comment: Well, it was from may 2016 lol...

Comment: Then the author of that tutorial is outdated ;-). Seriously, it's much easier to subclass `UITableViewCell` with `IBOutlet`s

Comment: Haha alright, will edit my code with that, thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is in the cell size. The labels are there but they are not in the visible area of the cell. Make your cell to be bigger or add right constraints in the storyboard.

Comment: It depends what you want but let say: top and left margins, width and height will be enough to display all the elements.